# Ajax call not working on datatable after pagination in Laravel

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel-5

I'm Using Ajax to Activate my registered users on my system and It works fine but only in first page of dataTables. when i'm to call another ajax request it does nothing.

Here is my Ajax code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // User Activate            
    $('.isActive').on('ifClicked', function(event){
        id = $(this).data('id');
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: SITE_URL + '/userActivate',

                data: {
                    '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val(),
                    'id': id
                },

                success: function(data) {

                toastr.success('Status Successfully Changed ! ', 'Congratulations', {timeOut: 5000});

                },

                error: function (jqXHR, exception) {    
                    console.log(jqXHR);
                    toastr.error('Something Error !', 'Status not Changed!')
                },
            });
            });

            $('.isActive').on('ifToggled', function(event) {
                      $(this).closest('tr').toggleClass('warning');
            });
 });
```

Comment: You should target all .isActive like ```$('*.isActive').on('ifClicked', function(event){};```

Dont leave the asterisk (*) to your targeting mechanis,

Answer (score 1):

Can you tell more specific so it would be easy to understand that where you are facing the issue in your ajax call after pagination.

Comment: I change the "$('.isActive').on('ifClicked', function(event)" to " $(document).on('click', '.isActive,' function() " at it works now. Thanks